# Download images to folder from PHP web page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have created a simple php web page that displays data from a mysql database in a table. Users can upload images for specific rows and these are stored in an upload folder on a server. I would like to be able to add the ability to click a button for a specific row and the image(s) for that row will be downloaded onto the users machine in a folder named after the part number of the row. Here is the upload image dialog box code:

```
//function to open a dialog where the user can upload an image to an existing row
$(function() 
  {

//$uniqueID = $('#uniqueID').val();

//opens the dialog form using the 'imgupdialog' fields outlined below 
    $( "#imgupdialog" ).dialog
({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: 
    {
Cancel: function() 
    {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},

});

//when the 'imgup' button is clicked the ID of the row will be obtained and the dialog will open
$(document).on('click', '.imgup', function()
    { 
//$( ".imgup" ).click(function() {
$('#uniqueID').val(($(this).attr('id')));
$("#imgupdialog").dialog( "open" );
    });

});
```

And here is the code that uploads the image:

```
$con = mysql_connect("", "");

if (!$con) {
die("Error: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("web", $con);

if(isset($_FILES['files']))
  {
$UniqueID = $_POST['var1'];
$desired_dir="uploads/";
$errors= array();

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{
$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
$file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
$file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  

if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
$errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }

$query="INSERT INTO web.PE_upload_data (ID, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE) VALUES ('$UniqueID', '$file_name','$file_size','$file_type')";


if(empty($errors)==true){
  if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
  {
mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);    // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else
        {  // rename the file if another one exists
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }
    else
    {
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error))
{
    echo "Success";
}
      }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it's not possible for the user to download a folder from the server or for the server to create a folder on the user machine, you can create a compressed folder `zip` containing the images instead and it will be downloadable. however some hosting servers disable the `zlib` library for security reasons, so it's better to check first.

Comment: Hi, thanks.I am just unsure how I would go about doing the download...

Comment: just want to confirm that you cannot specify where to download files, only the user can do that. And yea `zip` files if you really want to maintain folder structure. Or `tar`, but it isn't usually included in some OSes (e.g. windows, but people can download software to open those files)

Answer (score 0):

As many people have noted, the browser does not allow you to access the local machine.  There are various workarounds if you use Flash, Java, or my favorite - Silverlight saving to the IsolatedStorage folder.  Here is a bunch of sample code for using isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154(v=vs.95).aspx